# What does "realloc(): invalid next size" mean?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, realloc, memory-mapped-files

I will read some double information in file but my code make error.
This error message is "realloc(): invalid next size".
How do I fix this error?

If I reduce the number of readings in the file, the error disappears. Why didn't I understand?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define p1 0.5
#define p2 20

int main(void){

FILE *fp;
int i,j;

double *real_number;
double *temp;

real_number = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 1);

fp = fopen("input.txt","r");

for(i = 0 ; !feof(fp) ; ++i)
{
    real_number = (double *) realloc(real_number,sizeof(double)*2);

    fscanf(fp,"%lf",&(real_number[i]));
    printf("%.2f \n",real_number[i] );
    printf("i:%d\n",i );

}

return (0);
}
```

Comment: I think you want to allocate memory for the current number of values +1 in the loop, but you actually allocate the memory for 2 double values. `real_number = (double *) realloc(real_number,sizeof(double)*(i+1));`

Comment: [why `while (!feof())` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
real_number = (double *) realloc(real_number,sizeof(double)*2);
```

always allocates a memory of the same size that is only for two doubles.

So this loop

```
for(i = 0 ; !feof(fp) ; ++i)
```

can invoke undefined behaviour when `i` is greater than `1`.

Also the condition in the loop is incorrect because the end of the file can occur in this statement

```
fscanf(fp,"%lf",&(real_number[i]));
```

and it is not checked.

The loop can look for example the following way

```
double *real_number = NULL;
double value;

size_t i = 0;

for ( ; fscanf( fp, "%lf", &value ) == 1; i++ ) 
{
    double *tmp = realloc( real_number, ( i + 1 ) * sizeof( double ) );

    if ( tmp == NULL ) break;

    real_number = tmp;
    real_number[i] = value;
}
```

In this case after the loop the variable `i` will contain the number of inputted doubles.

Comment: Thank you I understand problem because of you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for the current number of values +1 in the loop, but you actually allocate the memory for 2 double values.

Change the `realloc` call to

```
real_number = (double *) realloc(real_number,sizeof(double)*(i+1));
```

BTW: You should check the result of `malloc` and `realloc` and all other functions that may report an error.

The loop `for(i = 0 ; !feof(fp) ; ++i)` is wrong. `feof` does not tell you that you will reach EOF, but only that you **have reached** EOF after a failed read operation. You should check the result of `fscanf` and after this you can use `feof` and `ferror` to distinguish between EOF, error related to the file or other errors like unexpected input. See [Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. :)